# How can I sort the date in the X axis properly on a Bar Chart in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I'm trying to order the date ascendantly in the X axis of the chart. And I've set it up that way here:

[image: Order]

However, this happens:

[image: Wrong order]

Is there a way to work around this? 25 January should be the last bar. I've tried changing data formats to see if it would order properly but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified how you are generating this graph, but it looks like you've done a Terms aggregation on the date field.  The order by you are showing is then for the terms count.  If you look right above that, it probably says order by: Metric count.  What you want it to say is Order by: term.

In any event, in general, you don't want to aggregate by date like that.  Instead choose a Date Histogram aggregation.  That will allow the time filter/aggregation bucket size to be changed.

Comment: Everything you said is correct. Thank you! Is there a way to hide the empty columns by any chance? I used the Date Histogram aggregation like you said and it orders the date perfectly, however it also shows days that have no  occurrences.